# How to make Google Chrome(or another browser) send a post request?

Tags: google-chrome, post

I'm tired of entering my information on one site everytime I visit it. Is there a way to make Chrome(or another browser) automatically do the post request?

If it was GET, it would be easy, but I don't have any background in web development.

Comment: By "*I'm tired of entering my information on one site everytime I visit it*" do you mean your login credentials? You could have your browser remember the credentials and it's auto-form fill features (if it has them). However that's not really a programming question.

Comment: It's not exactly login credentials, but credentials you can't go further without enterting them. Browser never asked me that on this site(it asks on others). How do I make it do a post request? This is the question, which IS programming related.

Comment: I think you're looking for something like this: http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=142893. But that isn't a programmatic solution and I don't quite understand how there could be one, sorry. The only way you can make a browser submit a POST request is to fill out a web page which has a form whose method is POST.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the chrome postman extension. It'll help making POST requests.

[postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm)